# Problem with a React-Native password textInput

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I created a textInput component for the user to enter a password.

When the user types a password in, the password appears hidden.

However, when the user presses the 'Show Password' button I would like the password color to change so it is visible.

I have function for this, however when it is executed, instead of changing the color it deletes the password text.

Function:

```
if (...) {
....
this.state.passTextColor = 'black';
....
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: need mor code to detect the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a sample application according to your requirements.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default class Example extends Component {
  state = {
    password: "",
    isPasswordHide: true
  };

  onChangeText = text => {
    this.setState({
      password: text
    });
  };

  changePasswordVisibility = () => {
    this.setState({
      isPasswordHide: !this.state.isPasswordHide
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={
            this.state.isPasswordHide
              ? styles.textInput
              : [styles.textInput, { color: "#ED3C20" }]
          }
          onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
          placeholder="Enter Your Password"
          value={this.state.password}
          secureTextEntry={this.state.isPasswordHide}
        />
        <Button
          title={this.state.isPasswordHide ? "Show Password" : "Hide Password"}
          onPress={this.changePasswordVisibility}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  textInput: {
    width: "80%",
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 5,
    marginBottom: 10
  }
});
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.